# Changes in aspx files won't show until rebuild

Tags: asp.net, rebuild

As I understand it, I should be able to change an aspx file in VS, update in the browser and then see the changes without rebuilding the entire solution. For me thats not the case...

Any ideas?

Edit:
I use VS 2008, .NET 3.5 and development server. It is a Web Application project and I always need to rebuild to see the changes in the aspx files. I use master pages and aspx controls. I use edit and continue and have no problem updating the code behind files without rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

If the change is affecting code behind in any way, you need to rebuild.

If not, can you give an example of what you change so we have a little more to go by  ;)

Comment: If some resources are being cached by the browser then you may need to do a total refresh <CTRL-F5>

Comment: As mentioned caching can surely be an issue. But that should be occasional only. Is this happening every single time? Is that a Web Application Project?

Comment: This is happening every time, I can never see any types of changes to aspx pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Web Application Template (versus the web site template) and you add controls to the aspx front-end code, it will automatically add it to the `<file_name>.cs.designer` partial class auto-generated code behind.  since this is part of the class, it needs to be compiled.

I think you need put more information into your question, like what change are you making?  What version of IIS are you using?  Are you using IIS or Cassini (Visual Studio Web Development Server)?